# Why doesn't my Javascript code work on Mozilla and upper versions of IE?

Tags: javascript, html

I have some Javascript code on my website to run a drop down menu. It works on IE 8 but not in Mozilla, chrome, IE 9 and 10. I cant understand why it happens. Here is my code.

```
<a href="javascript:"> 
<div id="idDesignMenu" onmouseover="ShowDropdown(idDesignMenu,idDesignMenuDrop,iMenuWidth)" >
<%=GetLanguagePhrase(65)%>
</div>
</a>
```

Here is Showdropdown in ../olap/Mdxview.asp:

```
function ShowDropdown(oMenu, oMenuDropDown) {
    //Set popup html
    var oDocument = oPopup.document;
    oDocument.open();
    var sHTML = "<html><head><link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='../style.css'></head><body topmargin=0 rightmargin=0 leftmargin=0 bottommargin=0 style='overflow:visible;border-width:0px;'>"
            + oMenuDropDown.innerHTML + "</body></html>";
    oDocument.write(sHTML);
    oDocument.close();

    //show popup
    oPopup.show(0, 0, 207, 50);
    var oPopupBody = oPopup.document.body;
    var iHeight = oPopupBody.scrollHeight;
    oPopup.hide();
    oPopup.show(0, 22, 207, iHeight, oMenu);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can we see the `ShowDropdown` function?

Comment: let me put it in question

Comment: When it doesn't appear in Mozilla, Chrome etc. are there any errors in the inspector console?

Comment: when you click or mouse over, nothing happens

Comment: Can you tell us what the console shows?

Comment: And if oPopup is an iFrame you need to read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947082/whats-the-most-concise-cross-browser-way-to-access-an-iframe-elements-window

Comment: var oPopup = window.createPopup();

Comment: It Just shows "Javascript:"

Comment: Console: ReferenceError: ShowDropdown is not defined. 
Showdropdown function defined  in other directory /olap/mxdesigfn.aspx

Comment: and sometimes this errors in console:
TypeError: window.createPopup is not a function  reportTree.aspx:37:13
ReferenceError: HideMenus is not defined   view.aspx:1:0
ReferenceError: OnLoad is not defined

Comment: I think I found The problem. it is because windows.Createpopup() does not work. is there any replacement?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5260811/what-is-the-equivalent-of-window-createpopup-in-firefox-safari-chrome-etc

Comment: Thanks bro!
I used IFrame but it didn't work again. I think before going to CreatePopoup, It cant open Showdropdown. maybe "Javascript:" can't open the desired function. but why?